# Recyclerview item long press not working using search view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an app which contains recyclerview with searchview on long press item is working fine in case of a normal list, But when I type anything using searchview it comes on the top but when I click on that item I am always getting an item from the normal list at position 0.How do I resolve this issue.

code:-

```
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {


            String charString = constraint.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                mFilterList = models;
            } else {
                ArrayList<UserListingModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (UserListingModel userListingModel : models) {
                    if (userListingModel.getUseName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || userListingModel.getUseName().toUpperCase().contains(charString.toUpperCase())) {
                        filteredList.add(userListingModel);
                    }
                }
                mFilterList = filteredList;
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = mFilterList;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mFilterList = (ArrayList<UserListingModel>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

searchview code:-

```
 mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Position");
            Users.mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Users.mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: please share Adapter code as well.

Comment: use [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85/raw/c9cd53e807a7fcf72549c0fb0f275019cafb30b7/MatchableRVArrayAdapte%2520(pure%2520RecyclerView%2520style,%2520no%2520implicit%2520TextView%2520mapping)) generic `Filterable` adapter as a base class and override its `matches()` method to implement your search criteria - in both cases (when filter is used or not) you can use `getItem` method to get the item from given position

Comment: Have you solved this issue ? @Rohan